# Rails 5 nested parameter permitted false

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, angular5

Rails 5 API nested attributes permitted false

```ruby
class TimeSheet < ApplicationRecord 
  has_many :job_times, inverse_of: :time_sheet
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :job_times, :allow_destroy => true 
end

class JobTime < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :time_sheet, optional: true
end
```

**Controller**

```ruby
def create
  puts "Job time  #{params.dig(:job_times)}"   
  @time_sheet = TimeSheet.create!(time_sheet_params)

  if @time_sheet.save
    render json: @time_sheet, status: :created, location: @time_sheet
  else
    render json: @time_sheet.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end

def time_sheet_params
  params.require(:time_sheet).permit(:first_name, :job_date, 
     job_times_attributes:  [:job_id, :job_department, :job_category, 
         :job_time, :is_overtime ]) 
end
```

Parameters:

```ruby
{"first_name"=>"GG", "job_date"=>"2018-05-22T00:50:19.000Z", "job_times"=>[{"job_id"=>"18001", "job_department"=>"CAD", "job_category"=>"Finishing", "job_time"=>"5", "is_overtime"=>""}, {"job_id"=>"18032", "job_department"=>"test", "job_category"=>"Finishing", "job_time"=>"2", "is_overtime"=>""}], "time_sheet"=>{"first_name"=>"GG", "job_date"=>"2018-05-22T00:50:19.000Z"}}

Job time  [<ActionController::Parameters {"job_id"=>"18001", "job_department"=>"CAD", "job_category"=>"Finishing", "job_time"=>"5", "is_overtime"=>""} permitted: false>, <ActionController::Parameters {"job_id"=>"18032", "job_department"=>"test", "job_category"=>"Finishing", "job_time"=>"2", "is_overtime"=>""} permitted: false>]
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The naming of your parameters is wrong, the problem might be on your form view.

You're sending `"job_times" => [...]` but you should be sending `"job_times_attributes" => [...]`.

Check that in your form you're nesting your `job_times` field inside a `fields_for` helper. For example, if `form` is your form object, then you should be doing something like:

```
<%= form.fields_for :job_times do |subform| %>
<%= subform.text_field :job_category %>
<% end %>
```

Or if you're generating your forms manually use `job_times_attributes` instead of `job_times`

Comment: Thanks. parameters comes from Angular. It comes ad job_times

Comment: In which case you have two options: 1. Tell your front-end Angular mates that you need it to come as `job_times_attributes` or Rails magic won't work. 2. Do the work yourself of mapping the attributes to the proper name, or to work with the given attributes create the appropriate methods in the model.